# Increasing page performance in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a GridView with 21000 record and I am fetching from DB using Stored Procedures. Initialy when I click on this page from my Web Application it takes too much time to load this page. Also I have a dropdown as filters in this page and when a dropdown value is selected it takes too much time to load the data. I use LINQ query to filter dropdown values.

How can I probably increase the performance of the page.

Comment: `Performance` from which context?

Comment: Theres a number of factors that affect your performance here, is it the stored procedures that are slow and the data access, or is it the rendering?

Comment: @theedam - When I run my stored proc in my DB it takes around 6 sec to execute and I also think page rendering is slow because of this?

Comment: you can go through this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx

Comment: Select only the Data from the Database you want to display on the page which is selected. This should increase it. If you have dropdownvalues, allready include them in the `Select`statment you send to the server and then again, only select as much rows as you need for the page which is selected.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ - I am using paging already in my page.

Comment: @Vicky it's not about paging it's about fetching only those rows from database which need to displayed on the page. And fetching the total rows to create pager.

Comment: +1 for @Șhȇkhaṝ Article, this is exaclty what i meant.

Comment: How are we supposed to get you are using paging from the problem statement?  "GridView with 21000 record"  Not nearly enough information to help you.  Voting to close.

Comment: Yeah. Magically help me please, I am too clueless to even provide basic information. Please explain me what a query execution plan is?  - is that the question?

Comment: @TomTom Not criticizing the people that provided answers but it has 3.

Answer (score 3):

You are in luck.  There is probably so much wrong with this scenario that you have lots of opportunity to improve.

You need to break down the problem into manageable chunks.

1. Analyze the stored procedure performance.  How long is it taking to return 21,000 records?
2. Is your filtering happening on the web server instead of in the database query?  That will add some extra overhead.
3. Even if the web browser receives the web page instantly, it cannot render 21,000 records in a reasonable timeframe.  Large grids add a lot of overhead to your page rendering time.

Probably your best bet for this page is convert it to use paging and only display somewhere between 10 and 100 records on the screen at once.  Your query should have your filters in it and then fetch the page of information that the user will see.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to **not to load all the records at a same time**.

The simple reason is because,

```
you are not going to show all the records at same time
```

Use, **Lazy loading** and load only those records that are currently being displayed.

This would make your page load faster and a significant performance improvement can be seen.

**The point to note here is that**: It will take more time for you to render html for those records than fetching them from database.

If you implement lazy loading, make sure you do **server side filtering**.

Do get confused with Client side filtering, which can produce wrong results

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

21000 records is too many to display in a single page. Instead I recommend you paging support to limit the amount of data retrieved at a time. Here is how you can implement:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67520/GridView-Paging-and-Sorting

The above link will address the dropdown issue as well.